# Is it possible to install SSRS Report Manager by itself?

Tags: reporting-services, reportmanager

I've been asked to look into writing an installer that will just set up Reporting Service's Report Manager by itself on a machine.

Is this possible?  My web searching has not given me a good answer.

Comment: This may depend on the version of the Server and service you use. I do not believe Azure will allow such a thing by default because the BIS has the Reporting Server tied to SQL installation. I assume any Reporting Server version prior to 2012 could be installed on backward compatible operating systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found an answer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179337(SQL.80).aspx

If you read down to the 'ADDLOCAL' bit you'll see you can install just Report Manager.  Something like this is required:

```
setup.exe /ADDLOCAL="RS_Manager"
```

Comment: Here's a version of the same info for 2008 R2: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx